# Upload de Imagem no Xamarin / c#

Tags: xamarin, upload

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em `Xamarin` que necessito fazer o upload de imagem (tanto no Android quanto no IOS), para um servidor. Procurei algo na internet e não encontrei.

Estou usando o `PostAsync` do `HttpClient`.

No servidor foi desenvolvido um `WS` que possui a seguinte estrutura de recebimento:

```
Key                          Value

FotoComprador               Arquivo JPG
FotoVendedor                Arquivo JPG
Localização                 Endereço do Imovel
numero                      numero do imovel
complmento                  complemento do imovel   
CEP                         CEP
Cidade                      Cidade
Estado                      Estado
```

O `Content-type` do `WS` é `form-data`.

Como devo definir o conteúdo da variável "informacoes" para executar o código abaixo?

```
var conteudo = new StringContent(informacoes, Encoding.Unicode, "application/json");
insereCorretor.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MoshiWSApiKey", MoshiKey);
insereCorretor.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Basic {0}", autorizacao));
var resultado = await insereCorretor.PostAsync(UrlIncluiRegistro, conteudo);
```

Comment: Qual é a tecnologia do seu backend (ws)?

Comment: C#. Já está desenvolvido e funcionando.